# How to post checkout data to component using Ajax?

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: Joomla.getOptions('system.paths').base+'/index.php?option=mypage&view=cartcheckout&task=cartcheckout_autoSave&tmpl=component&stepId='+stepId,
    type: 'POST',
    //async:false,
    data:values,
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response)
    {
        // do something
    },
    error: function(response)
    {
        // show ckout error msg
        console.log(' ERROR!!' );
        return e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

My Joomla version is  3.9.3 Stable.
I am getting error message on console

> ERROR!!

Is my url correct?

```
Joomla.getOptions('system.paths').base+'/index.php?option=mypage&view=cartcheckout&task=cartcheckout_autoSave&tmpl=component&stepId='+stepId
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This means that response is invalid JSON. What does the target page output?

Comment: @Askerman Can you give us more context? What extension(s) are you using?  Are you able to generate a more descriptive error?  Can you confirm that other variables hold their expected values?

Comment: Check the Network tab in your browser inspector. Go to the ajax request, them click the response tab. You may see an error there that's more relevant

Answer (score 1):

I would define the url simply like the following:

```
url:'index.php?option=com_mypage&view=cartcheckout&task=autoSave&tmpl=component&stepId='+stepId,
```

(If in the console you would see error due to double slash in the ajax request url, then try it also without slash at the beginning of the url)(And as @Sharky pointed to it in the comment, if the url starts without the leading slash, then the url will always point to the root, even if Joomla is intalled in a subfolder).

It should work this way. In the above, you can see that the first segment of the url (after index.php?) starts with com_mypage as it has to be your component name (or the component name which you communicate with). It will never work if it is just a page. It must be like: option=com_virtuemart or option=com_j2store or some other component name.

The other parts of the url look OK. (However, the task segment should be &task=mycontrollerfunction of the component).

I just do not see any reason to define the base path in the ajax url if you start this call from inside Joomla, it’s just totally unnecessary (and it will never work the way you tried, since in jQuery it does not mean anything).

I mean in jQuery you could start your url with the base like:

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + “/index.php?...”
```

But for this ajax call you really do not need that.

Comment: Starting the URL with index.php works for en-gb but if I rightly remember causes issues with multilingual sites

Comment: @Lodder - maybe. I’ve never experienced that with an ajax call to a controller function. As I see regarding this question we will never know what the artist’s original purpose was. :)

Comment: Remove leading slash. With it, the URL always points to the root directory even if Joomla is installed in a subfolder.